# How can I fix the text overflowing out of the box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, flexbox

When hover effect working i wanna show hero name in flexbox items. Now when hover effect not working too you can see hero names. Names must be inside the boxes when the effect works and must not overflow out. In the solution I found, flex items are created with javascript. I could do it if it was done manually in html, but I don't know how fixing with javascript. How can I solve this problem?

```js
    const data = { result: { data: { heroes: [ { id: 1, name: "npc_dota_hero_antimage", name_loc: "Anti-Mage", name_english_loc: "Anti-Mage", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 2, name: "npc_dota_hero_axe", name_loc: "Axe", name_english_loc: "Axe", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 3, name: "npc_dota_hero_bane", name_loc: "Bane", name_english_loc: "Bane", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 4, name: "npc_dota_hero_bloodseeker", name_loc: "Bloodseeker", name_english_loc: "Bloodseeker", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 5, name: "npc_dota_hero_crystal_maiden", name_loc: "Crystal Maiden", name_english_loc: "Crystal Maiden", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 6, name: "npc_dota_hero_drow_ranger", name_loc: "Drow Ranger", name_english_loc: "Drow Ranger", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 7, name: "npc_dota_hero_earthshaker", name_loc: "Earthshaker", name_english_loc: "Earthshaker", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 8, name: "npc_dota_hero_juggernaut", name_loc: "Juggernaut", name_english_loc: "Juggernaut", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 9, name: "npc_dota_hero_mirana", name_loc: "Mirana", name_english_loc: "Mirana", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 11, name: "npc_dota_hero_nevermore", name_loc: "Shadow Fiend", name_english_loc: "Shadow Fiend", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 10, name: "npc_dota_hero_morphling", name_loc: "Morphling", name_english_loc: "Morphling", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 3, }, { id: 12, name: "npc_dota_hero_phantom_lancer", name_loc: "Phantom Lancer", name_english_loc: "Phantom Lancer", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 13, name: "npc_dota_hero_puck", name_loc: "Puck", name_english_loc: "Puck", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 14, name: "npc_dota_hero_pudge", name_loc: "Pudge", name_english_loc: "Pudge", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 15, name: "npc_dota_hero_razor", name_loc: "Razor", name_english_loc: "Razor", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 16, name: "npc_dota_hero_sand_king", name_loc: "Sand King", name_english_loc: "Sand King", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 17, name: "npc_dota_hero_storm_spirit", name_loc: "Storm Spirit", name_english_loc: "Storm Spirit", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 18, name: "npc_dota_hero_sven", name_loc: "Sven", name_english_loc: "Sven", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 19, name: "npc_dota_hero_tiny", name_loc: "Tiny", name_english_loc: "Tiny", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 20, name: "npc_dota_hero_vengefulspirit", name_loc: "Vengeful Spirit", name_english_loc: "Vengeful Spirit", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 21, name: "npc_dota_hero_windrunner", name_loc: "Windranger", name_english_loc: "Windranger", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 22, name: "npc_dota_hero_zuus", name_loc: "Zeus", name_english_loc: "Zeus", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 23, name: "npc_dota_hero_kunkka", name_loc: "Kunkka", name_english_loc: "Kunkka", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 25, name: "npc_dota_hero_lina", name_loc: "Lina", name_english_loc: "Lina", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 31, name: "npc_dota_hero_lich", name_loc: "Lich", name_english_loc: "Lich", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 26, name: "npc_dota_hero_lion", name_loc: "Lion", name_english_loc: "Lion", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 27, name: "npc_dota_hero_shadow_shaman", name_loc: "Shadow Shaman", name_english_loc: "Shadow Shaman", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 28, name: "npc_dota_hero_slardar", name_loc: "Slardar", name_english_loc: "Slardar", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 29, name: "npc_dota_hero_tidehunter", name_loc: "Tidehunter", name_english_loc: "Tidehunter", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 30, name: "npc_dota_hero_witch_doctor", name_loc: "Witch Doctor", name_english_loc: "Witch Doctor", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 32, name: "npc_dota_hero_riki", name_loc: "Riki", name_english_loc: "Riki", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 33, name: "npc_dota_hero_enigma", name_loc: "Enigma", name_english_loc: "Enigma", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 34, name: "npc_dota_hero_tinker", name_loc: "Tinker", name_english_loc: "Tinker", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 35, name: "npc_dota_hero_sniper", name_loc: "Sniper", name_english_loc: "Sniper", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 36, name: "npc_dota_hero_necrolyte", name_loc: "Necrophos", name_english_loc: "Necrophos", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 37, name: "npc_dota_hero_warlock", name_loc: "Warlock", name_english_loc: "Warlock", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 38, name: "npc_dota_hero_beastmaster", name_loc: "Beastmaster", name_english_loc: "Beastmaster", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 39, name: "npc_dota_hero_queenofpain", name_loc: "Queen of Pain", name_english_loc: "Queen of Pain", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 40, name: "npc_dota_hero_venomancer", name_loc: "Venomancer", name_english_loc: "Venomancer", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 41, name: "npc_dota_hero_faceless_void", name_loc: "Faceless Void", name_english_loc: "Faceless Void", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 42, name: "npc_dota_hero_skeleton_king", name_loc: "Wraith King", name_english_loc: "Wraith King", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 43, name: "npc_dota_hero_death_prophet", name_loc: "Death Prophet", name_english_loc: "Death Prophet", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 44, name: "npc_dota_hero_phantom_assassin", name_loc: "Phantom Assassin", name_english_loc: "Phantom Assassin", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 45, name: "npc_dota_hero_pugna", name_loc: "Pugna", name_english_loc: "Pugna", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 46, name: "npc_dota_hero_templar_assassin", name_loc: "Templar Assassin", name_english_loc: "Templar Assassin", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 47, name: "npc_dota_hero_viper", name_loc: "Viper", name_english_loc: "Viper", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 48, name: "npc_dota_hero_luna", name_loc: "Luna", name_english_loc: "Luna", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 49, name: "npc_dota_hero_dragon_knight", name_loc: "Dragon Knight", name_english_loc: "Dragon Knight", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 50, name: "npc_dota_hero_dazzle", name_loc: "Dazzle", name_english_loc: "Dazzle", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 51, name: "npc_dota_hero_rattletrap", name_loc: "Clockwerk", name_english_loc: "Clockwerk", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 52, name: "npc_dota_hero_leshrac", name_loc: "Leshrac", name_english_loc: "Leshrac", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 53, name: "npc_dota_hero_furion", name_loc: "Nature's Prophet", name_english_loc: "Nature's Prophet", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 54, name: "npc_dota_hero_life_stealer", name_loc: "Lifestealer", name_english_loc: "Lifestealer", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 55, name: "npc_dota_hero_dark_seer", name_loc: "Dark Seer", name_english_loc: "Dark Seer", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 56, name: "npc_dota_hero_clinkz", name_loc: "Clinkz", name_english_loc: "Clinkz", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 57, name: "npc_dota_hero_omniknight", name_loc: "Omniknight", name_english_loc: "Omniknight", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 58, name: "npc_dota_hero_enchantress", name_loc: "Enchantress", name_english_loc: "Enchantress", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 59, name: "npc_dota_hero_huskar", name_loc: "Huskar", name_english_loc: "Huskar", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 60, name: "npc_dota_hero_night_stalker", name_loc: "Night Stalker", name_english_loc: "Night Stalker", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 61, name: "npc_dota_hero_broodmother", name_loc: "Broodmother", name_english_loc: "Broodmother", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 62, name: "npc_dota_hero_bounty_hunter", name_loc: "Bounty Hunter", name_english_loc: "Bounty Hunter", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 63, name: "npc_dota_hero_weaver", name_loc: "Weaver", name_english_loc: "Weaver", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 64, name: "npc_dota_hero_jakiro", name_loc: "Jakiro", name_english_loc: "Jakiro", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 65, name: "npc_dota_hero_batrider", name_loc: "Batrider", name_english_loc: "Batrider", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 66, name: "npc_dota_hero_chen", name_loc: "Chen", name_english_loc: "Chen", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 3, }, { id: 67, name: "npc_dota_hero_spectre", name_loc: "Spectre", name_english_loc: "Spectre", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 69, name: "npc_dota_hero_doom_bringer", name_loc: "Doom", name_english_loc: "Doom", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 68, name: "npc_dota_hero_ancient_apparition", name_loc: "Ancient Apparition", name_english_loc: "Ancient Apparition", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 70, name: "npc_dota_hero_ursa", name_loc: "Ursa", name_english_loc: "Ursa", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 71, name: "npc_dota_hero_spirit_breaker", name_loc: "Spirit Breaker", name_english_loc: "Spirit Breaker", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 72, name: "npc_dota_hero_gyrocopter", name_loc: "Gyrocopter", name_english_loc: "Gyrocopter", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 73, name: "npc_dota_hero_alchemist", name_loc: "Alchemist", name_english_loc: "Alchemist", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 74, name: "npc_dota_hero_invoker", name_loc: "Invoker", name_english_loc: "Invoker", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 3, }, { id: 75, name: "npc_dota_hero_silencer", name_loc: "Silencer", name_english_loc: "Silencer", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 76, name: "npc_dota_hero_obsidian_destroyer", name_loc: "Outworld Destroyer", name_english_loc: "Outworld Destroyer", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 77, name: "npc_dota_hero_lycan", name_loc: "Lycan", name_english_loc: "Lycan", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 78, name: "npc_dota_hero_brewmaster", name_loc: "Brewmaster", name_english_loc: "Brewmaster", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 3, }, { id: 79, name: "npc_dota_hero_shadow_demon", name_loc: "Shadow Demon", name_english_loc: "Shadow Demon", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 80, name: "npc_dota_hero_lone_druid", name_loc: "Lone Druid", name_english_loc: "Lone Druid", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 3, }, { id: 81, name: "npc_dota_hero_chaos_knight", name_loc: "Chaos Knight", name_english_loc: "Chaos Knight", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 82, name: "npc_dota_hero_meepo", name_loc: "Meepo", name_english_loc: "Meepo", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 3, }, { id: 83, name: "npc_dota_hero_treant", name_loc: "Treant Protector", name_english_loc: "Treant Protector", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 84, name: "npc_dota_hero_ogre_magi", name_loc: "Ogre Magi", name_english_loc: "Ogre Magi", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 85, name: "npc_dota_hero_undying", name_loc: "Undying", name_english_loc: "Undying", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 86, name: "npc_dota_hero_rubick", name_loc: "Rubick", name_english_loc: "Rubick", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 3, }, { id: 87, name: "npc_dota_hero_disruptor", name_loc: "Disruptor", name_english_loc: "Disruptor", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 88, name: "npc_dota_hero_nyx_assassin", name_loc: "Nyx Assassin", name_english_loc: "Nyx Assassin", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 89, name: "npc_dota_hero_naga_siren", name_loc: "Naga Siren", name_english_loc: "Naga Siren", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 90, name: "npc_dota_hero_keeper_of_the_light", name_loc: "Keeper of the Light", name_english_loc: "Keeper of the Light", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 91, name: "npc_dota_hero_wisp", name_loc: "Io", name_english_loc: "Io", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 3, }, { id: 92, name: "npc_dota_hero_visage", name_loc: "Visage", name_english_loc: "Visage", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 3, }, { id: 93, name: "npc_dota_hero_slark", name_loc: "Slark", name_english_loc: "Slark", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 94, name: "npc_dota_hero_medusa", name_loc: "Medusa", name_english_loc: "Medusa", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 1, }, { id: 95, name: "npc_dota_hero_troll_warlord", name_loc: "Troll Warlord", name_english_loc: "Troll Warlord", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 96, name: "npc_dota_hero_centaur", name_loc: "Centaur Warrunner", name_english_loc: "Centaur Warrunner", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 97, name: "npc_dota_hero_magnataur", name_loc: "Magnus", name_english_loc: "Magnus", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 98, name: "npc_dota_hero_shredder", name_loc: "Timbersaw", name_english_loc: "Timbersaw", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 99, name: "npc_dota_hero_bristleback", name_loc: "Bristleback", name_english_loc: "Bristleback", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 100, name: "npc_dota_hero_tusk", name_loc: "Tusk", name_english_loc: "Tusk", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 101, name: "npc_dota_hero_skywrath_mage", name_loc: "Skywrath Mage", name_english_loc: "Skywrath Mage", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 1, }, { id: 102, name: "npc_dota_hero_abaddon", name_loc: "Abaddon", name_english_loc: "Abaddon", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 103, name: "npc_dota_hero_elder_titan", name_loc: "Elder Titan", name_english_loc: "Elder Titan", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 104, name: "npc_dota_hero_legion_commander", name_loc: "Legion Commander", name_english_loc: "Legion Commander", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 106, name: "npc_dota_hero_ember_spirit", name_loc: "Ember Spirit", name_english_loc: "Ember Spirit", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 107, name: "npc_dota_hero_earth_spirit", name_loc: "Earth Spirit", name_english_loc: "Earth Spirit", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 3, }, { id: 109, name: "npc_dota_hero_terrorblade", name_loc: "Terrorblade", name_english_loc: "Terrorblade", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 110, name: "npc_dota_hero_phoenix", name_loc: "Phoenix", name_english_loc: "Phoenix", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 111, name: "npc_dota_hero_oracle", name_loc: "Oracle", name_english_loc: "Oracle", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 3, }, { id: 105, name: "npc_dota_hero_techies", name_loc: "Techies", name_english_loc: "Techies", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 112, name: "npc_dota_hero_winter_wyvern", name_loc: "Winter Wyvern", name_english_loc: "Winter Wyvern", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 113, name: "npc_dota_hero_arc_warden", name_loc: "Arc Warden", name_english_loc: "Arc Warden", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 3, }, { id: 108, name: "npc_dota_hero_abyssal_underlord", name_loc: "Underlord", name_english_loc: "Underlord", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, { id: 114, name: "npc_dota_hero_monkey_king", name_loc: "Monkey King", name_english_loc: "Monkey King", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 120, name: "npc_dota_hero_pangolier", name_loc: "Pangolier", name_english_loc: "Pangolier", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 119, name: "npc_dota_hero_dark_willow", name_loc: "Dark Willow", name_english_loc: "Dark Willow", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 121, name: "npc_dota_hero_grimstroke", name_loc: "Grimstroke", name_english_loc: "Grimstroke", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 129, name: "npc_dota_hero_mars", name_loc: "Mars", name_english_loc: "Mars", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 126, name: "npc_dota_hero_void_spirit", name_loc: "Void Spirit", name_english_loc: "Void Spirit", primary_attr: 2, complexity: 2, }, { id: 128, name: "npc_dota_hero_snapfire", name_loc: "Snapfire", name_english_loc: "Snapfire", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 123, name: "npc_dota_hero_hoodwink", name_loc: "Hoodwink", name_english_loc: "Hoodwink", primary_attr: 1, complexity: 2, }, { id: 135, name: "npc_dota_hero_dawnbreaker", name_loc: "Dawnbreaker", name_english_loc: "Dawnbreaker", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 1, }, { id: 136, name: "npc_dota_hero_marci", name_loc: "Marci", name_english_loc: "Marci", primary_attr: 0, complexity: 2, }, ], }, }, };
const container = document.querySelector("#photo");

data.result.data.heroes.forEach(item => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("flex-item");

    const heroName= item.name_loc;
    const linkparameter = item.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace("npc_dota_hero_","");

    li.innerHTML = `
        <img
            src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/apps/dota2/images/dota_react/heroes/${linkparameter}.png"
            alt="${heroName}"
        />
        <li>${heroName}</li>
        
        
    `;

    container.appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.flex-container {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 10em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.balancer {
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hover-value {
  font-size: 0px;

  -webkit-transition: font-size 1s;
  transition: font-size 1s;
}

button:hover .hover-value {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= , initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <ul id="photo" class="flex-container"></ul>
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    

</body>

</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gokhanyurtsever/pen/YzrjzgQ)

Comment: Note that `<li>` as direct child of `<li>` is invalid markup. Why is your issue any different by using javascript than raw html? Using classes and css still works the same

Comment: If you want to use js,maybe you can try `$( ".flex-item" ).hover(function(){})`.But I think css is ok.

Comment: Try changing `<li>${heroName}</li>` to `${heroName}` since you're setting the `innerHTML` so it's already a `<li>`.

Comment: first of all if i add pictures like `<li class="flex-item"><img src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/apps/dota2/images/dota_react/heroes/abaddon.png" alt="abaddon"></li>` to html yeah i can fixing flex items in css but i give to hero pictures from api. In this case flex item creating automatically from js and i dont know how can i change <li> tag. Because in html file dont have <li> tag.